# Silverlight 4 - Download an html page from a different domain IN BROWSER?

Tags: c#, silverlight, httpwebrequest, silverlight-4.0, cross-domain

I am trying to download a page using Silverlight 4 (http://google.com/) from a different domain than where the app is hosted.  I'm simply curious if this is possible in the browser.  I know I can do it out of the browser, as I tried it already, but trying it in the browser gives a security exception (understandable).

I'd like to know if this can even be done, and if so, how?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is known as cross domain access.  The domain you want to download the page from has to allow cross domain access for Silverlight (or Flash) apps via a policy file.  Details can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645032(VS.95).aspx)